# dynamic target url htaccess url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I use this rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^main/subold/(.*)$ /main/subnew-monthname/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

to redirect domain/main/subold/whatever.php to domain/main/subnew-monthname/whatever.php

I am changing the monthname part of the subnew-monthname folder every month. I can off course just change it each month in htaccess so the url with subold will be redirecting to the url with subnew-monthname but I was wondering if it is possible to make the "monthname" part dynamic so it just searches for month name or month number without constantly changing the rule in htaccess.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In `main/subold/`, create an `.htaccess` file with the following `mod_rewrite` rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(rewrites)
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/main/subold/rewrites.php?page=$1 [R=301]
```

Then, also in `main/subold/`, create a `rewrites.php` file with the following script:

```
$requestedURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$whatever = str_replace('/main/subold/rewrites.php?page=','',$requestedURI);
$currentMonth = strtolower(date("F"));
$redirectedURI = '/main/subnew-'.$currentMonth.'/'.$whatever;

header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header('Location: '.$redirectedURI);
```

Answer (score 0):

My other answer works (and may be appropriate for other scenarios), but I've just discovered *RewriteCond Time and Date Variables*, so the answer below may be exactly what you're looking for:

In `main/subold/`, create an `.htaccess` file with the following `mod_rewrite` rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} 01
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/main/subnew-january/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} 02
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/main/subnew-february/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} 03
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/main/subnew-march/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} 04
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/main/subnew-april/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} 05
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/main/subnew-may/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} 06
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/main/subnew-june/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} 07
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/main/subnew-july/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} 08
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/main/subnew-august/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} 09
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/main/subnew-september/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} 10
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/main/subnew-october/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} 11
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/main/subnew-november/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} 12
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/main/subnew-december/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```